# Check the date in a dropdown list decrement by 1 in java

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to this site and new to using Selenium and Java.  I am trying to write code to check that the options stored within a dropdown list of 5 items decrement by 1 from todays date.  So first option is yesterdays date, second 2days ago, third is 3days ago, etc.  Taking into consideration that if the day is Monday, the date needs to be the previous friday.. Can anyone help?

Many Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Welcome to SO, share your code so that others know what you have tried and can help to fix the errors or answer your questions

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getDate(int daysBefore) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); // For formating the date
        // Or if you're american:           ("MM/dd/yyyy")
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // Create a calendar
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -daysBefore); // Put it back however may days specified
        return df.format(calendar.getTime()); // Format it
    }
```

The argument 'daysBefore' is how many days ago you want it to give you.  So getDate(1) will give you yesterday, getDate(2) will give you days ago e.t.c.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was trying to parse the date first of all and read in all of the dates..  Thats as far as I got.  Had a problem with parsing the date.  It is in the following format: Friday, 30, August, 2013 (preliminary)

Comment: @Test
 public void DropdownDates () throws ParseException {
  
  Select optionDropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(OptionTypeDropdownXpath)));
  
  optionDropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(OptionTypeDropdownXpath)));
 
  optionDropdown.selectByIndex(0);
  String firstoption = optionDropdown.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
  
  String oldstring = "dd,MM,dd,yyyy";
  Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(oldstring);
  
  firstoption = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
  System.out.println(firstoption);

Comment: Thank you Ryxuma - will this check that the dates in my drop down are todays date -1 each time? :-)

Comment: I can't really read it, would you be able to put it in your original post? Once you've put it in highlight it and press ctrl-k to format it properly :-)

Answer (score 0):

In java array, list etc. is 0 based, that is why you get 1 back.